# Sequelize-auto cannot connect to a named MSSQL instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

My database on MSSQL is not on the default instance, but a named instance, say MSSQL2014.

I have difficulty when using command line to generate the model from the instance

The command I used is:

```
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d database -h localhost/MSSQL2014 -u sa -p 1433 -x testPassword -e mssql
```

I have also tried to use a command with -c option

```
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d database -h localhost/MSSQL2014 -u sa -p 1433 -x testPassword -e mssql -c config.json
```

For config.json

```
{ dialectOptions: {
            instanceName: 'NameOfTheMSSQLInstance'
        } }
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting back?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is the following

```
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d database -h localhost-u sa -p 1433 -x testPassword -e mssql -c config.json
```

And then this:

```
// config.json
{ 
  dialectOptions: {
    instanceName: 'MSSQL2014'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, You saved my tons of time.. :) but JSON should be 
"dialectOptions": {
      "instanceName": "MSSQL2014"
    }